# Add item to JSON array using JsonPatchDocument

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, json-patch

I am trying to add an element to a JSON array using Microsoft's JsonPatch implementation in .NET 6:

```json
JSON input:
{ "foo": [ 1 ] }
Expected JSON output:
{ "foo": [ 1, 2 ] }
```

Following [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I ended up with the following code:

```cs
string input = @"{ ""foo"": [ 1 ] }";
dynamic obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(input);
var patch = new JsonPatchDocument();
patch.Add("/foo/-", 2);
string output = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
Console.WriteLine(output); // throws JsonPatchException, expected { "foo": [ 1, 2 ] }
```

I expect the `foo` property of my object to contain an array equal to `[1, 2]`, but instead it fails with the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Exceptions.JsonPatchException: The target location specified by path segment '-' was not found.

A `Replace` operation on the `foo` property successfully updates the `ExpandoObject`, but the `Add` operation fails. Am I missing something obvious?

I also tried using `JsonNode` instead of `ExpandoObject` to no avail (`JsonNode obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(input);`). The code throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, as a workaround, I am using [JsonPatch.Net](https://json-everything.net/json-patch). The code looks similar:

```cs
string input = @"{ ""foo"": [ 1 ] }";
JsonNode obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(input);
var patch = new JsonPatch(PatchOperation.Add(JsonPointer.Parse("/foo/-"), 2));
PatchResult patchResult = patch.Apply(obj);
string output = JsonSerializer.Serialize(patchResult.Result);
Console.WriteLine(output); // { "foo": [ 1, 2 ] }
```